# SQL Joins to retrieve NULL values for rows which are not present in another table

Tags: sql, join, db2

I have 2 tables in DB2 as below:

Table A:

```
Key     ID  SubID
Abc123  576  10
Abc124  577  12
Abc125  578  14
```

Table B:

```
ID  SubID
576  10
576  11
577  12
577  13
578  14
578  15
```

I want output something like this :

```
  Key     ID  SubID
  Abc123  576  10
  Null    576  11
  Abc124  577  12
  Null    577  13
  Abc125  578  14
  Null    578  15
```

I joined table A and table B on ID column by using Left/Inner joins but still I am not getting the desired output as mentioned above .

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you just need an outer join, have you tried

```
Select a.Key, b.Id, b.SubId
from TableB b
left join TableA a on a.ID = b.ID and a.SubID = b.SubID;
```

Comment: Thanks , this works . I was missing on adding a.SubID = b.SubID condition

Comment: Just add order by 3 to the solution offer by @Stu